# I have this error with tresitter and neovim "Failed to load parser for lenguage 'html': uv_dlopen: dont found the specified process"

Tags: html, neovim, treesitter, neovim-plugin

I don't know the reason for the error, previously it worked normally. It is also happening to me with ".yaml. Can someone tell me what I can try or how to fix it? I have found similar errors but with .cpp although they have not helped me at all. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZj2o.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1ywj.png)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgB5Q.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.